# How do I convert TCHAR to int

Tags: c++, windows

I want to convert a TCHAR to an int, but when I convert it I get the ASCII value to an int, not the number value.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int converttoint()
{
    TCHAR tchar[2];
    wcscpy_s(tchar, TEXT("5"));

    int i = tchar[0];

    cout << i << endl;

    return i;
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    converttoint();

    string in;
    cin >> in;
}

Output: 53
```

But I want i to be 5.

How can this be done?

Comment: how about you use `_ttoi`.

Comment: Dont use TCHAR anymore, this isn't the 90's. But if you do @GillBates is right.

Comment: `TCHAR` isn't a standard c++ thing.

Comment: This is winapi32 so i need to use tchar

Comment: Check the discussion: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/57906/ It may help you

Comment: @ Gill Bates _ttoi() solved it - thank you.

Comment: @Niklas: `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, so just use the `wchar_t` functions.

Comment: The Win32 API uses UTF-16. The "A" versions of the functions are lossy wrappers for Windows 95.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to convert a string (containing an integer) to an `int`, you can use some C functions like `atoi()` (for `char` ANSI strings) or `_wtoi()` (for `wchar_t` Unicode UTF-16 strings), or others that take a locale as an additional input parameter: you can read more on [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx).

If you want to use the TCHAR model, the corresponding functions are `_tstoi()` or `_ttoi()`, as described in the aforementioned MSDN documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it the old school way and take '0', this works because digits will be ordered, taking ascii as an example 53 is the decimal value for '5' and 48 is the decimal value for '0', and so taking our implicitly cast values, (53-48) is equal to the decimal value of 5. Something like :
 `int i = tchar[0] - '0';` will work.

Comment: Your assumption is mandated by the standard.  `'5' - '0'` will always return `5`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Edited, to include and example of why '5' - '0' works.

Comment: I would not rely on ascii.  I would include the standardies.  C++ can use other character sets like EBCDIC

Comment: @NathanOliver it's just for an example, the difference between the decimal value of a decimal char and the decimal char '0', will be the decimal equivalent of the decimal char, I just think it's easier to understand when you can look at a char set table.

Comment: _TCHAR is used for Unicode, and doesn't necessarily work with ASCII. This is dangerous (and may not even work).